# How to mount Rails Engines automatically/dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When using a mountable Engine in a Rails application it is necessary, to mount this Engine in the parent apps `config/routes.rb` file like this:

```
mount MyEngine::Engine, at: "/my_engine"
```

But, would it be also possible somehow to mount the Engine in the parent app **dynamically** e.g. in the initializer call during installation of the Engine with `bundle install`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
    config.my_engine = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
    initializer 'my_engine.configuration' do |app|
      if app.config.my_engine[:mounted_path]
        app.routes.append do
          mount MyEngine::Engine => app.config.my_engine[:mounted_path]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then in the main application in `config/application.rb`, you can set

```rb
config.my_engine.mounted_path = "/some_path_here"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the late reply, I just found now the time to test this, and its working like a charm!